# How to set value and text in select

Tags: angularjs

I've been trying to figure out how to set this particularly select like this:

```
<select name="ddlStatus" id="ddlStatus" class="form-control" ng-model="status" ng-      change="onChangeStatus()">
    <option ng-repeat="status in orderStatus" value="{{ status.ID }}">{{ status.Name }}  </option>
</select>
```

How can i set is without ng-repeat and insted using ng-options? Ive tried a lot of solution but nothing solves it like this way i show above..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `as` in `ng-options`:

```
<select ng-model="status" ng-options="status.ID as status.Name for status in orderStatus"></select>
```

Alternatively, angular seems smart enough to use the whole `status` object as the value even when you specify some sub-field like `name` as its label.

```
<select ng-model="status" ng-options="status.Name for status in orderStatus"></select>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/4ApFG/1/

Answer (score 2):

You can use the whole model as the value like:

```
<select ng-options="status.Name for status in orderStatus" ng-model="status">
</select>
```

That way you can just get the selected id over `status.ID`. Angular will handle the value model linking stuff for you.

Or of course the id is also possible. Although at least for me it seems to be a bit confusing because you will have the array index in the generated html and the id as the actual value.

```
<select ng-options="status.ID as status.Name for status in orderStatus" ng-model="status">
</select>
```

Additionally asigning the whole model to `status` makes a lot more sense than just the id.

Comment: Simply using `ng-options="status.Name for status in orderStatus"` seems to have the same effect.